# Can I die fighting for my country, even against Muslim attackers?

Tags: halal-haram, war, martyr

**Can a Muslim man die for his country?**

If it is attacked by a nation that has **both Muslims and non-Muslims in the army**, although the non-Muslims are the majority and are the leaders of the country. When it comes to war the enemy will be an enemy whether Muslim or non-Muslim and the majority of the enemy is non-Muslims so my question is: **As a Muslim is it permissible to join that war to defend my people and my home?**

Secondly **if I kill a Muslim enemy without knowledge**, will I go to hell for that?

Lastly **if I capture a Muslim brother who was with the enemy**, do I have to consider him as a hypocrite and kill him or I keep him as a hostage until the war ends?

Comment: If answer can include fighting with all muslims army(say another muslim COUNTRY, nowaday) to defend your COUNTRY, that will be great

Answer (score 3):

An important angle to consider is that in Islam, nationalism or tribalism is if not outright haram extremely disliked.

"The believing men and believing women are allies of one another. They enjoin what is right and forbid what is wrong and establish prayer and give zakah and obey Allah and His Messenger. Those - Allah will have mercy upon them. Indeed, Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise."

Surah Tawbah, 71

I believe you are referring to serving in a national army. 
Self defense is certainly lawful, however hadith speak for the need of the Muslims to hold together as a unified political entity. The identification and adherence to a national identity is contrary to this goal. Note- loving the land where you were born and come from is not the same thing as saying that a colored peace of cloth represents your identity, and then fighting, killing, and dying based on the identity that that piece of cloth represents.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed a very good question.

1. Defence is the must thing, Islam emphasizes on. If muslims attack
   you, even if they are 100% muslims, you must defend your land.

The reason of defence becomes more stronger, as Muslims are ordered not to attack fellow Muslims, so if they do attack, defence is a must strategy.

2. If a muslim has attacked your home, even with acknowledgement that he is a muslim, you are not going to hell for killing him.
3. If you capture a Muslim in war, while defending then You should dealt with him as Islam orders the behaviour with prisoners.

Comment: FIghting for your home and for your COUNTRY is different thing. If another muslim country attacks a muslim country, and they say we won't harm you if you don't fight us. WHat about than? it snot so simple

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing that tell you that a muslim life is more precious than any other life, don't make the case about a muslim country. your question should be, can I die defending my country, that's all. then yes you should defend yourself from attacks but not carry the attacks yourself. if someone is coming to get you no matter what he is, you should defend yourself, you're not going to stop and say ohh wait you are a muslim so it is ok you can kill me. 
Also you should look for peace before the fight though, and peace again with everybody no matter what they are. Don't make difference between people.

Comment: In the Targhib wa’ l-Tarhib of Imam al-Mundhiri, 3/276 it has the following hadith from `Abd Allah ibn `Amr ibn al-`As (Allah be well pleased with him) that he said:

“I saw the Messenger of Allah (saw) performing tawaf around the Holy Ka`ba saying to it: ‘how pure and good you are! how pure and good your fragrance is! how great and exalted you are! and how great and exalted your sanctity is! But by Him in Whose hand is Muhammad’s soul, the sanctity of a believer’s blood and property in the sight of Allah is greater than your sanctity!’“

Comment: Al-Bara’ reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “The passing of the world is less significant to Allah than the killing of a believer without a just cause.”

Source: Sunan Ibn Mājah 2619

Comment: Technically two righteous groups shouldn't be fighting one another. So what you're suggesting is practical

Answer (score -1):

The term "Muslim attackers." If they're attacking you for violent reasons, they are not Muslims.

You have a right to protect yourself, your family, and your country from attackers. In the Quran, it says to protect yourself and fight to protect your people if others attack you. If they are the ones attacking, they aren't really Muslims.

Fighting for protection is okay, but fighting just to hurt others is haram.